# UglifyJs JavaScript API for JSON minification?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, minify, uglifyjs2

So I am looping through files in a directory via Node and want to minify them with UglifyJs.

The API is dead easy for JavaScript files:

```
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js")

// Looping here
UglifyJS.minify(listOfAllFiles[i])
```

However, the files I need to minify are JSON files, so this is producing an eval error. In the command line, if you are minifying JSON, you just pass `--expr` and it will evaluate as a single expression. Any idea how to pass this into the options object of the JavaScript API?

Cheers.

Comment: JSON =/= JavaScript. The syntax is different. There's very little about JSON that _could_ be minified, even.

Comment: @Cerbrus Removal of whitespace. As I explicitly stated, UglifyJs supports JSON minification.

Comment: I don't see any `expr` parameter in it's [documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2).

Comment: I updated the tags a little.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're not dead set on UglifyJS, you could solve this with plain JavaScript, because JSON can't really be uglified that much. To remove all whitespace, use:

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(listOfAllFiles[i]))
```

(Assuming `listOfAllFiles[i]` is the JSON string.)

Comment: Ah very helpful! This will indeed do the trick and is super easy.

Answer (score 2):

UglifyJS doesn't minify JSON.

You can minify using [jsonminify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonminify) instead.

Contrary to what others are saying, JSON minification is useful, as it allows you to use comments in JSON (which are not allowed in .json files).